# How do I take the end off of a String in Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, regex, eclipse

I have a string that looks like this:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myurl.com%2Fbarcodes%2Fimages%2F024543634737.jpg
```

I just want the end of the string past the / (%2F) so I get the following:

```
024543634737.jpg
```

Is there a RegEx or something that I can use with Java? Can someone post some quick code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String splitString = "/"; // you can change it to %2F
String s = "http://www.myurl.com/barcodes/images/024543634737.jpg";
int index = s.lastIndexOf(splitString);
String result= null;
if(index > -1){
    result = s.substring(index+splitString.length());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (using `String.lastIndexOf` and `String.substring` methods) -

```
String input = "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myurl.com%2Fbarcodes%2Fimages%2F024543634737.jpg";
System.out.println(input.substring(input.lastIndexOf("%2F") + 3));
```

Output:

> 024543634737.jpg

Comment: Just check to make sure the input `String` is not `null`

Comment: @jonny2k9: Yes ofcourse, otherwise it will result in an NPE. But I think it's not required in the code I posted. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use lastIndexOf() method of String class. `lastIndexOf()` Searches for the last occurrence of a character or substring.
see like this,

```
String str = "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myurl.com%2Fbarcodes%2Fimages%2F024543634737.jpg";

int i = str.lastIndexOf("%");

String result = str.substring ( i );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] array= "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myurl.com%2Fbarcodes%2Fimages%2F024543634737.jpg".split("%2F");

String own = array[array.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(myString.indexOf("/")>=0){  
    myString = myString.substring(myString.lastIndexOf("/")+1, myString.length());
}
```